# VBA to manipulate Pivot Table Content

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2010 and I have a bizarre issue that I wish to resolve using VBA.

I have a Pivot Table which pulls data from a data source contained within a separate data sheet. This Pivot Table will ultimately be shared with other people.

After creating the pivot table, I delete the worksheet so the raw data isn't visible. Ultimately, I want to create a locked down view of what is contained in the pivot table, i.e. I don't want to allow the user to see all the fields and their values after the table has been created (such as address etc).

e.g.

if I have the following dataset

```
ID  First Name  Last Name   Street            Salary
1   George  Bush            The Street        100
2   Peter   Sellers         2 The Close       200
3   Paul    Scholes         3 The Ness        400
4   David   Cameron         4 The Avenue      300
5   Robert  Redford         5 The Yard        250
```

And I create Pivot Table then delete the data sheet, it will still allow the end user to manipulate all columns within the pivot table. I would like to hide certain fields based on the type of end user, for the sake of simplicity, just the Street field. How can I remove this value from the list of fields (using VBA) that are able to be used within the pivot table?

Comment: If a certain user type is not going to use the "Street" field, can you build the pivot table from an additional datasheet that omits this column?

Comment: You can build a "permissions" like table into your spreadsheet and place code in the `Workbook_Open` event to check the username of who is opening the file, then build a dynamic pivot table based on that users permissions and the desired columns. You could also build a pivot for each user type and just `xlVeryHidden` the other sheets so the user cannot get to the other pivot tables or data sheets that support them. (unless there super savvy in VBA of course)